# React Native Paper text inside button not wrapping

Tags: css, react-native-paper

I'm tryin to break the Text of some text inside a button so that it doesn't overflow and show three dots. I've tried flexWrap:'wrap' and flexShrink:1 on the parent but it's not budging, not sure how to fix:

```
          <RectangleButton
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#4DB33D", alignItems: "flex-start" }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                color: "#E8E7D5",
                fontSize: 20,
                lineHeight: 30,
                flexWrap: "wrap",
                // width: "100%",
              }}
            >
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              {alphabet[index].toLowerCase()}:{" "}
              <Text>
                {answer}
              </Text>
              {"\n"}
            </Text>
          </RectangleButton>
```

This is my custom button:

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { ButtonProps, Button } from "react-native-paper";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

interface RectangleButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const RectangleButton = ({ children, ...props }: RectangleButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Button {...props} style={[styles.btn, props.style]}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default RectangleButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btn: {
    width: width * 0.9,
    borderRadius: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});
```